# Find not working

Tags: find, osx, zsh, oh-my-zsh

The `find` command is not working as expected on my OSX with oh-my-zsh. A few examples:

```
$ find . -name test
find: .: Invalid argument

$ find
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

$ find --version
find: illegal option -- -
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

$ find version
find: .: Invalid argument
```

I'm not sure what's happening here cause the same examples work as expected on my Linux machine. Any ideas on how to debug it?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but forgot to mention. No, it's not aliased. Result of `alias | grep find` is `afind='ack -il'
fd='find . -type d -name'
ff='find . -type f -name'`

Comment: What does `type find` say?

Comment: @pfnuesel `find is /usr/bin/find`

Comment: And it's working in `bash`? What if you don't load your `.zshrc`?

Comment: Interesting. It does work in bash. How would I not load `.zshrc` while using `zsh`?

Comment: I changed the name of my `.zshrc` file. Find works as expected now, but my other zsh configurations are missing so staying that way is not an option.

Comment: I've installed `findutils` according to @Dalvenjia's answer and it helped. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because you are trying to use the GNU find, which is default in Linux, but Mac OS X comes with BSD find which has many differences.

To install GNU find you will need Homebrew, pretty easy to install, just follow http://brew.sh/

After that you can install findutils:

```
brew install findutils
```

More info and other tools to mimic a Linux environment on your Mac here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities

Other option is to read the BSD find man pages and adjust your command. Just run `man find`, you'll see at the top of the screen "BSD General Commands Manual" confirming that in fact you have BSD find.

Comment: Installing `findutils` helped, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Law29 BSD vs BSD? Did you mean BSD vs GNU?

Comment: BSD find has differences wrt GNU find (or rather the contrary), but your answer would be improved if you explained why find . -name test is not valid using BSD find.

Comment: @Najki -- yes I meant BSD vs GNU. I haven't looked at the history of `find` specifically, but generally today's BSD tools have stayed closer to the the 1970s versions, while GNU tools have lots of added bells and whistles (some would say too much, others appreciate, YMMV).

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The given command in the question is a standard way of using any `find`. None of it is specific to GNU `find`.