# Why is the GNU find command telling me that any valid path is an "invalid argument"?

Tags: debian, find, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is a possible duplicate of [Find not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277914/find-not-working), but since I am a new member I thought I'd ask a new question instead of commenting on that question's answer. Please forgive me and LMK if I should do otherwise.

I am seeing the following when running various `find` commands on a Windows 10 WSL/Debian system:

```
kenny@pc-name:/mnt/v$ find . -type f ! -iname "*.avi"
find: ‘.’: Invalid argument
kenny@pc-name:/mnt/v$ find /mnt/v -type f ! -iname "*.avi"
find: ‘/mnt/v’: Invalid argument
...5 other attempts to use the same command with other completely-valid paths, with the same result
kenny@pc-name:/mnt/v$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0.225-235f
...other irrelevant lines spat out by --version
```

As you can see, this issue is different to the one linked above since I *am* running GNU find. The only possible explanation that I can think of is that this is a WSL/Debian system, rather than pure Debian running on bare metal.

Any advice would be very much appreciated, thanks! :-)

**UPDATE:** In response to @Wildcard's comment, here are the results of further testing:

```
kenny@pc-name:/mnt/v$ find --help
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D debugopts] [path...] [expression]

default path is the current directory; default expression is -print
expression may consist of: operators, options, tests, and actions:
operators (decreasing precedence; -and is implicit where no others are given):
      ( EXPR )   ! EXPR   -not EXPR   EXPR1 -a EXPR2   EXPR1 -and EXPR2
      EXPR1 -o EXPR2   EXPR1 -or EXPR2   EXPR1 , EXPR2
positional options (always true): -daystart -follow -regextype

normal options (always true, specified before other expressions):
      -depth --help -maxdepth LEVELS -mindepth LEVELS -mount -noleaf
      --version -xdev -ignore_readdir_race -noignore_readdir_race
tests (N can be +N or -N or N): -amin N -anewer FILE -atime N -cmin N
      -cnewer FILE -ctime N -empty -false -fstype TYPE -gid N -group NAME
      -ilname PATTERN -iname PATTERN -inum N -iwholename PATTERN -iregex PATTERN
      -links N -lname PATTERN -mmin N -mtime N -name PATTERN -newer FILE
      -nouser -nogroup -path PATTERN -perm [-/]MODE -regex PATTERN
      -readable -writable -executable
      -wholename PATTERN -size N[bcwkMG] -true -type [bcdpflsD] -uid N
      -used N -user NAME -xtype [bcdpfls]      -context CONTEXT

actions: -delete -print0 -printf FORMAT -fprintf FILE FORMAT -print
      -fprint0 FILE -fprint FILE -ls -fls FILE -prune -quit
      -exec COMMAND ; -exec COMMAND {} + -ok COMMAND ;
      -execdir COMMAND ; -execdir COMMAND {} + -okdir COMMAND ;

Valid arguments for -D:
exec, opt, rates, search, stat, time, tree, all, help
Use '-D help' for a description of the options, or see find(1)

Please see also the documentation at http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/.
You can report (and track progress on fixing) bugs in the "find"
program via the GNU findutils bug-reporting page at
https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=findutils or, if
you have no web access, by sending email to <bug-findutils@gnu.org>.
kenny@pc-name:/mnt/v$ find /mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop -type f -name *.txt
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/info.txt
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/phone.txt
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/Uber.txt
kenny@pc-name:/mnt/v$ find /mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop -type f -iname *.txt
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/info.txt
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/phone.txt
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/test.TXT
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/Uber.txt
kenny@pc-name:/mnt/v$ find /mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop -type f -not -iname *.txt
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/desktop.ini
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/test.AVI
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/test.MKV
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/test.MP4
/mnt/c/Users/Kenny/Desktop/test.PDF
kenny@pc-name:/mnt/v$ find /mnt/v -type f -not -iname *.txt
find: ‘/mnt/v’: Bad file descriptor
kenny@pc-name:/mnt/v$ find . -type f -not -iname *.txt
find: ‘.’: Bad file descriptor
```

So as you can see, `find` has no problem recursing through my C: drive and finding the right files. The problem only exists on my V: drive, which is a network share mounted with `sudo mount -t drvfs '\\192.168.1.1\Videos' /mnt/v`. Also, while I was originally getting "invalid argument" errors, that has now changed to "bad file descriptor" in the space of an hour, even though no other changes have been made to this WSL system in that time! :S

Comment: What does `find --help` output?

Comment: @Wildcard - thanks for helping, please see the question update that I just posted :-)

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the windows subsystem. Did you try to make a bug report to MS?

Comment: @schily Yes I've reported it on the WSL GitHub issues page. Thanks :-)